# Alexander Whitney map

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

Let $$AW:C_*(X \times Y)\rightarrow (C(X) \otimes C(Y))_* $$ on singular chain complexes and $$f:C_*(X \times Y)\rightarrow (C(X) \otimes C(Y))_* $$ defined through $f_0=AW_0$. I want to show that $AW$ and $f$ are chain homotopic, so that there is a sequence $(h_n)_n$ of linear maps $$h_n: C_n(X \times Y)\rightarrow (C(X) \otimes C(Y))_{n+1}$$ so that $$d_{n+1}^{\otimes}\circ h_n+h_{n-1}\circ d_n=AW_n-f_n$$

Obviously, this is true for $n=0$ if we set $h_0=0$. Since I know that $AW$ is a natural chain map, I think i have to construct the other $h_n$ inductively, but here I am stuck.

Comment: Remark: The point of this exercise is that any chain map $C_*(X \times Y)\rightarrow (C(X) \otimes C(Y))_*$ is uniquely (up to chain homotopy) determined by what it does in degree 0. What you're trying to prove is part of the statement of the Eilenberg-Zilber theorem. The method of acyclic models furnishes a nice proof of the Eilenberg-Zilber theorem.